# Everytime I use content:"\005B" it becomes content:"�05B"

Tags: php, mysql, css

I have a CSS text which is stored into mySQL database.

It's stored to `ibf_css` table, `css_text` column. `css_text` collation is `latin1_swedish_ci`.

It's the way the web application I'm using works. The CSS is stored into the database and loaded with css.php. It's not the usual style.css like Wordpress.

I have this in my CSS

`#userlinks > span:before { content:"\005B";margin-right:4px; }`

Everytime I save it into database (through the web application), it changed to this

`#userlinks > span:before { content:"�05B";margin-right:4px; }`

This happens with every line which has `\0`. Like `\005D`, `\00D0`, etc. It changed to `�05D`, `�0D0`, etc.

If I edit with phpmyadmin, it's fine. But if I edit with the web application, it's troubled.

Help please? Much appreciated.

Comment: `CSS.PHP`? :O, does that work?

Comment: How are you inserting the text into the database?

Comment: @Mr.Alien Yes it works, really unconventional but if you open for example mywebsite.com/css.php?d=1_1.css it shows the CSS

Comment: @deceze There;s an admin panel to insert the text to database, something like this http://i.imgur.com/8ZrST.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`INSERT INTO foo ('bar') VALUES ('\0')` means you want to insert a *NUL byte*. When querying this again, you'll get an actual `0x00` byte back instead of `\0`. You need to **SQL escape** any data you insert into a database. Not just for cases like this, but **always**.

Please read [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/).

Comment: So everytime I update the CSS I've to write it as `\\005B` instead of `\005B`?

Comment: Thanks mate it works though kinda annoying because every time I update the CSS I have to rewrite it as `\\005B` (the first slash` always disappear after I update it so it became `\005B` again)

Comment: You don't need to do this *by hand*, you need to properly prepare your SQL query in code.